# PHP XMLReader Special Characters

Tags: php, xml, encoding, special-characters, xmlreader

I am using XMLReader, more specifically, [Jeremy Johnstone's plist processer](http://www.jeremyjohnstone.com/blog/2008-10-26-php-parser-for-os-x-plist-xml-files.html) to process a plist XML file. Some of the strings in the XML file contain special characters. One example is "Frédéric Chopin". When I try to print strings with special characters, they are not being displayed correctly. For example, "Frédéric Chopin" is shown as "FrÃ©dÃ©ric Chopin" instead.

What can I do so the string is displayed as "Frédéric Chopin"? Thanks!

Comment: You could set the encoding of your page to UTF-8 and have all your problems disappear in flash of light.. :)

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: *face palm* Thank you. I was just echoing directly from a PHP file and didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a UTF-8 string misinterpreted as some other encoding. You can use `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` to convert into whatever your site uses. I recommend the second one since it can generate HTML entities:

```
<?php
echo mb_convert_encoding($input, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the encoding. Be sure the display encoding matches the XML encoding, (e.g. `UTF-8`). I am not familiar with that plist processor, but it is possible you may have to set the encoding for the parser as well.